# Return specific rows, cascading results in column - If no 1 then multiple 2s, else if no 2s then 3, else if no 3, then multiple 4s

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, sql-server-2017

I am working with student data in MS SQL and have some very specific rules to follow.

### Sample Table

```
CREATE TABLE students (
    encounterId INT,
    studentId INT,
    positionId INT
);

INSERT INTO students
VALUES
(100,20,1),
(100,32,2),
(100,14,2),
(101,18,1),
(101,87,2),
(101,78,3),
(102,67,2),
(102,20,2),
(103,33,3),
(103,78,4),
(104,16,1),
(104,18,4),
(105,67,4),
(105,18,4),
(105,20,4);
```

### Table rules

The table shows student encounters where students are placed in a position between 1 and 4.
There can be multiple students in an encounter.
There can be only one student in position 1 in an encounter.
There can be only one student in position 3 in an encounter.
However, multiple students can be in positions 2 and 4 in an encounter.

### Business rules

The business rule is as follows for each encounter:

- If the encounter has a student in position 1, return that encounter's **row** (singular position 1), removing any positions 2-4 rows for that encounter
- ELSE if no position 1 THEN return the encounter's **rows** for students (can be multiple) in position 2, removing any positions 3 or 4 for that encounter
- ELSE if no positions 1-2 THEN return the encounter's **row** for students in position 3, removing any position 4 rows for that encounter
- ELSE if no positions 1-3 THEN return the encounter's **rows** for students in position 4

### Not quite working

Concatenation of the studentId value is acceptable, but not ideal. I've got this semi-working with a wonky series of unions and string_aggs. The rows with positionId=3 are problematic, as I've remarked in the code.

Additionally, this union/not like architecture works in my small development DB but will have serious performance issues in production DBs:

```
WITH tAll
AS (   SELECT
           encounterId,
           studentId,
           positionId
       FROM
           students)

SELECT
    encounterId,
    CAST(studentId AS VARCHAR) AS [studentId],
    1                          AS [ord]
FROM
    tAll
WHERE
    positionId = 1
UNION
SELECT
    encounterId,
    CAST(studentId AS VARCHAR),
    2 AS [ord]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            encounterId,
            STRING_AGG(studentId, ',')  AS [studentId],
            STRING_AGG(positionId, ',') AS [positionId]
        FROM
            tAll
        GROUP BY
            encounterId
    ) t2
WHERE
    positionId NOT LIKE '%1%'
    AND positionId NOT LIKE '%3%'
    AND positionId NOT LIKE '%4%'
UNION
SELECT
    encounterId,
    CAST(studentId AS VARCHAR),
    3 AS [ord]
FROM
    --tAll WHERE positionId=3 
    --Limiting to positionId=3 includes results (101,18,1) AND (101,78,3).. I just want (101,18,1)
    --Using the below code instead, but this creates other problems
    (
        SELECT
            encounterId,
            STRING_AGG(studentId, ',')  AS [studentId],
            STRING_AGG(positionId, ',') AS [positionId]
        FROM
            tAll
        GROUP BY
            encounterId
    ) t3
WHERE
    positionId NOT LIKE '%1%'
    AND positionId NOT LIKE '%2%'
    AND positionId NOT LIKE '%4%'
--This excludes 103 entirely since it has both positionId values of 3 AND 4... I just want (103,33,3)
UNION
SELECT
    encounterId,
    CAST(studentId AS VARCHAR),
    4 AS [ord]
FROM
    (
        SELECT
            encounterId,
            STRING_AGG(studentId, ',')  AS [studentId],
            STRING_AGG(positionId, ',') AS [positionId]
        FROM
            tAll
        GROUP BY
            encounterId
    ) t4
WHERE
    positionId NOT LIKE '%1%'
    AND positionId NOT LIKE '%2%'
    AND positionId NOT LIKE '%3%';
```

### What I want returned

| encounterId | studentId | ord |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 20 | 1 |
| 101 | 18 | 1 |
| 102 | 67 | 2 |
| 102 | 20 | 2 |
| 103 | 33 | 3 |
| 104 | 16 | 1 |
| 105 | 67 | 4 |
| 105 | 18 | 4 |
| 105 | 20 | 4 |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a top-1-per-group problem... with ties.

You can use window function to `rank()` in a subquery to rank students within each encounter, then filter on the top record(s) per group in the outer query:

```
select *
from (
    select s.*,
        rank() over(partition by encounterid order by positionid) rn
    from students s
) s
where rn = 1
order by encounterid
```

Another option uses `with ties` - but you can't control the ordering of the rows in the resultset:

```
select top (1) with ties *
from students s
order by rank() over(partition by encounterid order by positionid)
```

Another typical solution is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select *
from students s
where positionid = (select min(s1.positionid) from students s1 where s1.encounterid  = s.encounterid)
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!! How do I compare performance of these options and of the option from @venkataraman R below? The Execution Plans seem to indicate that the correlated subquery has fewer processing elements and fewer overall estimated rows to process; is that the winner from a performance standpoint?

Comment: @jtrauma: that would depend on your data, so you probably need to assess each solution in your database. The correlated subquery can take advantage of an index on `students(encouterid, positionid)`. The other answer scans the table twice, so I would not expect it to be faster than the above solutions (but - again - you would need to assess that).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for getting data for testing. Below query is working fine.

```sql
;with cte_minposition as
(
SELECT encounterId, min(positionid) as min_position FROM students
group by encounterId
)
SELECT * FROM students as s
inner join cte_minposition as m
on s.positionId <= m.min_position and s.encounterId = m.encounterId
```

| encounterId | studentId | positionId | encounterId | min_position |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 20 | 1 | 100 | 1 |
| 101 | 18 | 1 | 101 | 1 |
| 102 | 67 | 2 | 102 | 2 |
| 102 | 20 | 2 | 102 | 2 |
| 103 | 33 | 3 | 103 | 3 |
| 104 | 16 | 1 | 104 | 1 |
| 105 | 67 | 4 | 105 | 4 |
| 105 | 18 | 4 | 105 | 4 |
| 105 | 20 | 4 | 105 | 4 |

Comment: How do I compare the performance of your solution against @GMB's? Thanks!